# unable to find nearest geometry point in Sequelize - mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Here is model:

> ```
> 'use strict'; module.exports = () => {
> var restaurant = {
>     id: {
>         type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
>         primaryKey: true,
>         autoIncrement: true
>     },
>     businessCordinates: {
>         type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
>         allowNull: true
>     }
>
> };
>
> return sequelize.define('restaurant', restaurant); };
> ```

So I am trying to find the nearest point with some range in KM.

here is my query using Sequelize and dialect as mysql.:

> ```
> exports.search = (req, res) => {
>
> let where = {};
> if (req.query.lat && req.query.lng && req.query.range) {
>     var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
>     var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
>
>     query.where = Sequelize.where(
>         Sequelize.fn('ST_DWithin',
>             Sequelize.col('businessCordinates'),
>             Sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID',
>                 Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint',
>                     lat, lng),
>                 4326),
>             0.032),
>         true);
>
>     // var attributes = Object.keys(db.restaurant.attributes);
>
>     // var location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${lat} ${lng})')`);
>     // var distance = sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.literal('businessCordinates'), location);
>     // attributes.push([distance, 'distance']);
>
>
>     // query.attributes = attributes;
>     // query.order = distance;
>     // query.where = sequelize.where(distance, {
>     //     $lte: req.query.range
>     // })
> }
>
>
>
> db.restaurant.findAll(query).then(restaurants => {
>     return res.page(restaurants);
> }).catch(err => {
>     res.failure(err);
> }); };
> ```

So When I am trying to get restaurants like *{{host}}/api/restaurants?lat=40.741895&lng=-73.989308&range=12*

this query gives error like :  **sqlMessage=FUNCTION foodway_db.ST_DWithin does not exist**

let me know how to do this?

Comment: does the function ST_DWithin exist in your db ?  SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;

Comment: @feiiiiii    ST_DWithin  function not showing.  How to enable this.

Comment: you need to create the function in the db, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html